# Receiving numeric values and letters when reading text from file

Tags: c++, ifstream

When I try to read text from a file, I'm getting numeric values and letters in my output instead of just the text.

This is my `GreenLang.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class ScanErrors {
protected:
    char* element;
    char codeElement;
    std::string path;
    std::string source;

public:
    ScanErrors (std::string filePath) {

        std::ifstream fileRead;
        fileRead.open(filePath);
        while (!fileRead.eof()) {
            fileRead.get(codeElement);
            scan(codeElement);
        }
        fileRead.close();
    }
    
    void scan(char code) {
        std::cout << code << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::to_string(code);
    }
};

int main() {
    ScanErrors scanner("code.gl");

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code.gl:

```
Hello, World!
```

My output:

```
H
72e
101l
108l
108o
111,
44
32W
87o
111r
114l
108d
100!
33!
33
```

Why do these numeric values appear instead and how can I get the text value?

Comment: First of all: Please try to keep constructors small and simple. They should initialize the object to a well-known state, but not much more. Keep file-reading out of it.

Comment: Secondly, please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Thirdly, what are you really trying to do? Why are you using `std::to_string`? What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print only the characters and not their ASCII values, you can remove the line `std::cout << std::to_string(code);` from your scan function:

```
  void scan(char code) {
        std::cout << code << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no overload of [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) that takes a `char` as argument.

It will instead be converted to an `int`, and you get the string representation of the *numeric* `int` value.

If you look at [an ASCII table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) you will see that e.g. `72` is the numeric integer representation for the character `'H'`.

If you want to get a string containing the character, then there is a [`std::string` constructor overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that allows that:

```
std::cout << "String of only one single character: " << std::string(1, code) << '\n';
```